# dotnet set semantic version

Tags: .net, semantic-versioning, aspnet-api-versioning

Is there a way to actively modify the [versioning](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/library-guidance/versioning) of the `.csproj` files using the `dotnet` CLI? In the same way we can update the [npm version](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/commands/npm-version).

I need to modify the files, I'm not looking for `dotnet build -p:Version=1.2.3.4`.

OR for example with maven you can do this: `mvn versions:set -DnewVersion=1.2.3.4` which actually updates your `pom.xml`.

Comment: Would you accept setting the version at build time with a CLI parameter, or do you actually need to modify the `.csproj` file?

Comment: I actually need to modify the `.csproj` file. I know about `dotnet build -p:Version=1.2.3.4`.

Comment: csproj files are XML files. Edit them like you would any other XML file.

Comment: I want a tool that can do that, I don't want to manually open and edit the XML files, nor do I want to create a script for that. I added examples with `npm` and `mvn` which can do this task.

Comment: Try this one: https://github.com/TAGC/dotnet-setversion It uses `XDocument` to load, modify and save the csproj file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one: https://github.com/TAGC/dotnet-setversion

It uses `XDocument` to load, modify and save the csproj file.

Answer (score 2):

For clarity, are you looking to set the **Assembly Version** or **Semantic Version**? A semantic version only has 3 numeric parts: `<major>.<minor>.<patch>`.

For reference, these are the relevant MSBuild properties that you can set or pass via the CLI:

- `Version`: overall version; defaults to `1.0.0.0` if unset
- `AssemblyVersion`: the assembly version; defaults to `Version`
- `FileVersion`: the Win32 file version; defaults to `AssemblyVersion` if unset
- `VersionPrefix`: the version prefix; meant to serve as the numeric part of the semantic version; defaults to `Version` if unset
- `VersionSuffix`: the version suffix; meant to serve as the label part of the semantic version
- `PackageVersion`: the NuGet package (e.g. semantic) version; defaults to `$(VersionPrefix)-$(VersionSuffix)` if both are set; otherwise, `VersionPrefix`, which may default to `Version`

`dotnet pack --version-suffix beta.1` is equivalent to `dotnet pack -p:VersionSuffix=beta.1`

Regardless of which version you are trying to set (maybe even both), I would recommend just using native MSBuild if possible because it simplifies the process. If you want to manage the versions in one place, you can easily do this with **Directory.Build.targets**.

For example, let's assume your source layout is:

```
└─ src
    ├─ Project1
    ├─ Project2
    └─ Project3
```

By adding the file `src/Directory.Build.targets`, **all** projects will import the file automatically **without** any modification (e.g. zero-touch).

There's many ways you could configure it, but it *could* look something like:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">

  <PropertyGroup>
    
    <MajorVersion Condition=" '$(MajorVersion)' == '' ">1</MajorVersion>
    <MinorVersion Condition=" '$(MinorVersion)' == '' ">0</MinorVersion>
    <PatchVersion Condition=" '$(PatchVersion)' == '' ">0</PatchVersion>

    <VersionPrefix Condition=" '$(VersionPrefix)' == '' ">$(MajorVersion).$(MinorVersion).$(PatchVersion)</VersionPrefix>
    <AssemblyVersion Condition=" '$(AssemblyVersion)' == '' ">$(VersionPrefix).0</AssemblyVersion>
    
    <!-- replicates the old behavior of <major>.<minor>.* (ex: 1.0.*) in AssemblyInfo.cs -->
    <DaylightSavingTime>$([System.DateTime]::Now.IsDaylightSavingTime())</DaylightSavingTime>
    <FileBuildNumber>$([System.DateTime]::Today.Subtract($([System.DateTime]::Parse("1/1/2000"))).ToString("%d"))</FileBuildNumber>
    <FileBuildRevision Condition=" '$(DaylightSavingTime)' == 'True' " >$([System.Convert]::ToInt32($([MSBuild]::Divide($([System.DateTime]::Now.Subtract($([System.TimeSpan]::FromHours(1.0))).TimeOfDay.TotalSeconds),2))))</FileBuildRevision>
    <FileBuildRevision Condition=" '$(DaylightSavingTime)' == 'False' " >$([System.Convert]::ToInt32($([MSBuild]::Divide($([System.DateTime]::Now.TimeOfDay.TotalSeconds),2))))</FileBuildRevision>
    <FileVersion>$(MajorVersion).$(MinorVersion).$(FileBuildNumber).$(FileBuildRevision)</FileVersion>

  </PropertyGroup>

</Project>
```

*Figure 1: Directory.Build.targets*

This works really well if all of your projects use the same version numbers. A solution *usually* uses the same versions. If they don't, then it becomes a bit trickier. Although it would be possible to easily override just one part of version in a project (or projects), you indicated that was not an option. Another option would be to use an auto-generated value for patch; perhaps based on date. Then you'd never need to edit value.

If your versioning strategy is centrally managed this way, then IMHO, it's just as much effort to modify a single number with any text editor as it would be running some CLI command that you also have to install. The `dotnet-setversion` tool offers configuring a JSON file and that is same level of effort in updating a native MSBuild XML file albeit without requiring an additional tool.

> Aside: Just my option, but I would not recommend setting a semantic version label as suggested by `dotnet-setversion`. Instead, I would stick to the built-in `--version-suffix` parameter. There are many ways to hook that up into your build process or use it imperatively on-demand as needed.

It's also worth noting that there are many guardrails that prevent you from going off the tracks. If you use non-numeric values, the build will fail. If accidentally forget to increment the version or use a duplicate label, publish will be rejected. There's no tool that will prevent you from forgetting to increment unless you use auto-generation method.